# Is the "What's here?" Google maps feature known from the PC/Browser available on Android?

Tags: google-maps

The PC Version of Google Maps offers a **What's here?** feature (giving grid reference in decimal degrees) which is seemingly not available on the Nexus 7.

This is very useful for navigation to locations without a specific street or house number address, e.g. rural areas.

How can this feature be accessed or is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

Just tap and hold the point of interest on the map, and then tap the location when it pops up. Then select **What's nearby?**.